# SQL count duplicate values across multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Item table:

```
ItemID    ItemNumber    CategoryID
----------------------------------
1         1             1
2         2             1
3         3             1
4         1             2
5         2             2
6         3             2
7         1             3
8         2             3
9         3             3
```

A Category table:

```
CategoryID    CategoryNumber    GenreID
---------------------------------------
1             1                 1
2             2                 2
3             3                 3
```

And a Genre table which is not relevant.

The requirement is for me to make sure that ItemNumber 1 is unique to GenreID 1. i.e., there can be only one Item with an ItemNumber of 1 that is in a category belonging to the Genre with a GenreID of 1.

How do I write a SQL query to get a count of Items with the same ItemNumber in the same Genre, or Items that violate this business rule? It's really boggling my mind and I need expert SQL help.

Comment: `select count(itemid) as cnt, categoryid from itemtable left jon categorytable on .... group by itemtable.categoryid`?

Comment: Well, it looks like your real problem is to design your tables with appropriate restrictions so you cannot have an assignment that breaks your rules.  Can you describe your business constraints: can  a category belong to more than one Genre? can an item belong to more than one category?  Your use of "ItemID" and "CategoryID" appear to be convenience indices .. what are the "real" keys to the information in the Item, Category and Genre tables (or are there more tables involved)?

Comment: @ErstwhileIII a Category can only belong to one Genre, and an Item can only belong to one Category. The "real" key of Item, if there is one, is ItemID since ItemNumber is not unique across all items. But nobody in the business uses ItemID or cares what it is. Actually, they refer to Items as GenreNumber:CategoryNumber, even though each Category can have multiple Items. It's a mess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try below query

```
select i.ItemNumber, c.GenreID, count(*)
from Item i, Category c
where i.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
group by i.ItemNumber, c.GenreID
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: How to do this if you have 50 tables? A where for each one of them is not going to be funny :(

Answer (score 2):

You need to join the tables together and count the distinct genres per item.  The resulting query is something like this, if I understand your problem correctly:

```
select i.itemnumber, count(distinct c.genreid) as numgenres
from items i join
     categories c
     on i.categoryid = c.categoryid
group by i.itemnumber
having count(distinct c.genreid) > 1
order by numgenres desc;
```

Comment: This is my bet as well. If the OP wants to enforce the business rule at the database level, an insert/update trigger per table that raises an exception can be used.

Comment: This tells me that, for instance, ItemNumber 536 is used in 16 Genres, which is not really what I need to know. I need to know if there is more than one Item with ItemNumber 536 in any single Genre.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading correctly, you want to make sure that every item in a genre has a distinct item number?

```
SELECT c.GenreID, count(i.ItemNumber) totalCount, count(distinct i.ItemNumber) distinctCount
FROM Items i JOIN Category c ON i.CategoryID=c.CategoryID  
GROUP BY c.GenreID
```

Comment: This works, but I accepted [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25495417/1015595) instead because it makes it's easier to see the offending Items.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, you would like to see a count for each set of (ItemNumber, CategoryID).  It seems to me you don't have to join to the category table at all.  The following should do it:

```
     Select ItemNumber, CategoryID, count (*)
     From ItemTable 
     Group by ItemNumber, CategoryID
```

And to just retrieve the instances of duplicates, tack on a Having clause, and maybe even an Order By to get the biggest offenders at the top of your list:

```
     Select ItemNumber, CategoryID, count (*)
     From ItemTable 
     Group by ItemNumber, CategoryID
     Having count(*) >1
     Order by count(*) desc
```

Then, you might want to expand this to return the unique IDs of these offenders:

```
         Select ItemID, ItemNumber, CategoryID, CountOfInstances
             From (Select CountOfInstances = count (*)
                     From ItemTable 
                     Group by ItemNumber, CategoryID
                     Having count(*) >1
                     )Duplicates
                Inner Join ItemNumber 
                    on ItemTable.CategoryID = Duplicates.CategoryID 
                        and ItemTable.ItemNumber = Duplicates.ItemNumber
```

Comment: Not quite. There might be only one Item with ItemNumber 1 in the Category with CategoryID 1, but that doesn't mean there couldn't be another Item with ItemNumber 1 in the Genre that Category belongs to.