# Writing SQL statement to select from multiple rows

Tags: sql

This might be a silly question to ask. I will appreciate any kind of help.

I'm trying to write a query that count the number of rows based on the logic as below:

count no rows where username = @username and friendsname = @friendsname and username = @friendsname and @friendsname = @username where status = 0

consider the table in the diagram below:

[image]

The query should return 1 since id '18' and id '20' have reciprocal values. How will this query be written?

I have written the query as follows which doesn't work:

```
        bool flag = false;
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    query.Append("SELECT Count(id) from friends where username=@username AND friend_username=@friend_username AND username = @friend_username AND friend_username = @username");
    query.Append("  AND status=0");

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Config.ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query.ToString(), con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", username));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@friend_username", friendusername));
            if (Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 0)
                flag = true;
        }
    }

    return flag;
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question correctly. As per my understanding, You just need to find the number of rows which satisfy your conditions?  I didnt undersyand how you got the result 17.

Comment: try reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495160/sql-count-duplicate-values-across-multiple-tables

Comment: @Steve sorry I meant 18 and 20

Comment: @perplexedDev 17 is the row id. I want to count the number of rows that have status as 0 and usrname and friend_username reciprocal to each other in both rows

Comment: Have you made any effort to write this query yourself? It seems you have a concept of the logic you want to use. Have you at least tried?

Comment: @Ken White I wrote the query like this : SELECT Count(id) from friends where username=username AND friend_username=friend_username AND username = friend_username AND friend_username = username AND status = 0. It doesn't work

Comment: Please [edit] that information into your question itself, instead of putting it in comments where it can't be seen. It's helpful to show the effort you've put into solving it yourself into your question, as it shows that a) you've tried to solve it yourself before posting here, and b) you're not just trying to use us as a code-writing service.

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba you may want to accept the answer, or specify what's still missing in current ones, if they are giving you wrong results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you're trying to count rows given a specific `@username` and `@friendusername` that have reciprocal values based on your conditions.

Below query should help, though - I have not tested it in action!

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as reciprocal_values_no
FROM table_name tbl1
WHERE 
  username = @username
  AND friend_username = @friendusername
  AND status = 0
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM table_name tbl2 WHERE tbl1.username = tbl2.friend_username AND tbl1.friend_username = tbl2.username )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select username,friend_username,status, count(*)
  from table_name
  group by username,friend_username,status
  having count(*) > 1
```